# Onedrive/Azure API Code Flow for authentication sends me to my redirect url, but does not give me a code attached to the url

Tags: oauth-2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#step-1-get-an-authorization-code

I have followed this step to a tee, login with success, get redirected, and there is no code with the redirect url as the tutorial promises.
The following link is my version with the credentials.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=a383dd3b-8306-4902-93d3-f5a33fe4a445&scope=Files.Read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient

I get taken to this page and sign into an account under the same namespace. [Login view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV4aA.png)

After signing into a proper login, all I get in return is redirected to my redirect URI with no code attached to the end like the tutorial says I should. All I need is access to 3 files on my onedrive, but I can't seem to make it past OAuth2. Here is what I get redirected to. https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient

Comment: P.S. I removed the app as it is just a test app. I started a new test app and am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

From first look it seems that the redirect_uri is wrong. This should be the endpoint where you receive the authorization code and then exchange it for the rest of the OAuth process.

I work with Pathfix and we solve the problem of OAuth token management using a serverless infrastructure.

To summarize, here is what your url should look like

```
 https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=a383dd3b-8306-4902-93d3-f5a33fe4a445&
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.All%20offline_access&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=https://your endpoint
```

An additional note on the scope. Note above that the scope definition for token should be as I have specified above

Comment: Thanks, I go this part figured out. Now I have an issue with it being a government account. I get the error message "Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request." as  I pass in the code from the url and request data. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4458250/deployment-from-team-foundation-server-to-azure-us-government-cloud. I followed this tutorial with no luck.

Comment: Can you accept the answer and raise a new question, There might be some discussion around the government account. I’ll read up and get back to you

Comment: I only have 11 reputations so I can't upvote, but I figured it out a couple of weeks ago and explained the government account difference.

Answer (score 0):

It all works the same. I just made sure my app was open to all tenants and replaced the .com with .us in all links but the redirect uri. Hopefully, this helps someone else. For example, my data is on a sharepoint, but the microsoft graph api works the same for all accounts with a difference in .us, .com, and few others.